# NullPointerException & QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, hibernate, model-view-controller, hql

I want to search record between two dates. and here what I got in my breakpoints:
1.NullPointerException
2.QuerySyntaxException

I don't have any idea with the Error. I hope someone can help me.
I'm using MVC Java and Hibernate HQL
This is my code for Model:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)  LocalDate startDt;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)  LocalDate endDt;
    public LocalDate getStartDt() {
        return startDt;
    }
    public void setStartDt(LocalDate startDt) {
        this.startDt = startDt;
    }
    public LocalDate getEndDt() {
        return endDt;
    }
    public void setEndDt(LocalDate endDt) {
        this.endDt = endDt;
    }
```

also this is my DAO Hibernate:

```
public Map<String, Object> viewSched(DeliverySchedule sched) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();        
        StringBuffer dynamicSql = new StringBuffer();
        
        //Generate sqlCount query
        StringBuffer hqlQueryCount = new StringBuffer("select count(*) from DeliverySchedule ds where 1=1 ");
        /*StringBuffer hqlQuery = new StringBuffer(" from DeliverySchedule ds left join ds.location loc left join ds.product p left join ds.driver u where 1=1  ");*/
        StringBuffer hqlQuery = new StringBuffer(" from DeliverySchedule ds where 1=1 ");
        
                
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sched.getSearch())) {
            dynamicSql.append("and ( lower(ds.driver.firstName) like lower(:search) or lower(ds.location.name) like lower(:search) ) ");
            //getSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("date1", "%"+sched.getDeliveryDate()+"%").setParameter("date2","%"+sched.getDeliveryDate()+"%").list();
        }
        
        if(sched.getStartDt()!=null && sched.getEndDt()!=null){
            dynamicSql.append(" and ((where ds.deliveryDate) between (:startDt) AND (:endDt)) ");
        }
        
//      dynamicSql.append("and ds.isCancel = :isCancel ");
        
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sched.getOrderBy())) {
            dynamicSql.append("order by ").append(sched.getOrderBy());          
            if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sched.getSortBy())) {
                dynamicSql.append(" ").append(sched.getSortBy());
            }
        }
    
        final String sql =  hqlQuery.append(dynamicSql).toString();
        final String sqlCount =  hqlQueryCount.append(dynamicSql).toString();
        
        
        Query query = getSession().createQuery(sql);
        Query queryCount = getSession().createQuery(sqlCount);
        
         
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sched.getSearch())) {
            query.setParameter("search", "%"+sched.getSearch()+"%");
            queryCount.setParameter("search", "%"+sched.getSearch()+"%");
            
        }
        
        if(sched.getStartDt()!=null && sched.getEndDt()!=null){
               query.setParameter("startDt","%"+sched.getStartDt()+"%").setParameter("endDt","%"+ sched.getEndDt()+"%");
               queryCount.setParameter("search", "%"+sched.getStartDt()+"%");
               queryCount.setParameter("search", "%"+sched.getEndDt()+"%");
            }

        /*query.setParameter("isCancel", false);
        queryCount.setParameter("isCancel", false);*/
        
        if(!InventoryUtility.isNull(sched.getBegin())) {
            query.setFirstResult((sched.getBegin() - 1) * getSize());
            query.setMaxResults(getSize());
        }
        
        Integer count = Integer.parseInt(queryCount.list().get(0).toString());
        List<DeliverySchedule> results = query.list();
        
        map.put(KEY_COUNT, count);
        map.put(KEY_LIST, results);
        return map;
    }
```

view:

```
<form>
                        from <form:input path="startDt" name= "startDt" pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd" type= "date" style="box-sizing:border-box; height:30px;"/>
                        to <form:input path="endDt"  name= "endDt" type= "date" pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd" style="box-sizing:border-box; height:30px"/>
                        <input type= "submit" class="btn btn-success" style=height:30px;/>
                        </form>
```

Your answer much appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is with `and ((where ds.deliveryDate) between (:startDt) AND (:endDt))` . Should this be `and (ds.deliveryDate between (:startDt) AND (:endDt))`

Comment: why i don't need to use the 'where'?